# LTspice a voltage source as a function of time

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I saw the ability to control R by time in someone's drawing, tried it, and it worked fine. Then, I thought that I could use that "time" keyword also to control the voltage of a DC source. However it didn't work. It gives an error:

> Error on line 2 : vcc n001 0 time*2
>        Unknown parameter "time*2"
>   Vcc: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
>   .OP point found by inspection.

So, is there an easy way, as easy as it is with the resistor value, to do what I want?

Comment: If in doubt, try to wrap your expression with {}. So you may write {time*2} and see how that works.

Comment: @jonk nope, didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you try to make an **alterating** voltage source with a **DC** source.
Use Arbitrary behavioral voltage source (BV) instead.
You don't need curly braces for that, just `V=time*10m`

Comment: I can't find an "arbitrary behavioral voltage source"

Comment: @muyustan look for bv